# Why can't I vote to close a question I flagged for closure in the past?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

As I was going over the Review Close Votes Queue I came upon a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526187/localizable-push-notifications) that seemed familiar.

When I tried to vote to close the question (as duplicate) I got a message saying that I `already flagged this question for closure`.

I checked my flags, and indeed found a duplicate flag for this question, which was deemed helpful (at the time of flagging that question I didn't have 3K rep, so I couldn't cast a close vote).

My question is why can't I vote to close this question? I never voted to close it. I just flagged it. I assume the person who handled the flag decided to follow my suggestion to close the question as duplicate and cast a close vote (the question currently has one close vote), but that wasn't my close vote.

And if you convince me it's the desired behavior not to let me vote to close that question, then that question shouldn't have appeared in my Close Votes Queue in the first place.